# HiveQL Date_Add issue

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hiveql

Using Hue 2.3.1-402, I'm noticing some bugs with HQL's date_add function giving a result out by one day, potentially due to UTC timezone issues.

Running the two codes below yields different results:

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(TO_DATE('2015-02-22'), 25) AS d1_b
```

> 2015-03-19

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(TO_DATE(d1), 25) AS d1_b 
FROM
(SELECT '2015-02-22' as d1) a
```

> 2015-03-18

A similar issue occurs when the date_add function evaluates over multiple rows of data. Running without the to_date conversion (to keep it a string) and gives the same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested your code as below on hive 13.1.  It worked perfectly.  I am not sure why you are using to_date() which Returns the date part of a timestamp string as your dates appear to already have the timestamp stripped off.  Your date '2015-02-22' is a string so the to_date() should not be doing anything.

My results are below:

```
select date_add('2015-02-22',25) from table;
```

Results in 2015-03-19

```
select date_add(to_date('2015-02-22'),25) from table;
```

Results in 2015-03-19

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(TO_DATE(d1), 25) AS d1_b 
FROM
(SELECT '2015-02-22' as d1 from table) a;
```

Results in 2015-03-19

You will need to leave more information for someone to help you troubleshoot further.

Comment: Recently discovered there are known issues with Hive date serialization using the ORC file format causing this - it's an issue with our current set up.

Thanks for testing